On the injectivity of the trace operator
Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^N$ be an open bounded domain with $\partial \Omega$ be class $C^1$. I have to show that if $f \in H^1(\Omega)$ and $g \in W^{1,\infty}(\Omega)$ then the product $fg$ is in $H^1(\Omega)$ and that $\gamma(fg) = \gamma(f)$, with \gamma the trace operator.
I have showed the first part, that $fg$ is in $H^1(\Omega)$, using the product rule in Sobolev spaces. I tried to do the later part, but I don't know how to do it. I've never used the trace operator and it's really new for me. I tried to show that $fg - f$ is in $H_0^1(\Omega)$ because that is equivalent to show that $fg-f \in Ker (\gamma)$ but I couldn't make any advance.
I also tried to use the Green Formula to do something with the trace that appears in the formula, but I didn't advance neither.
Can someone help me?
Thanks in advance

The statement is sadly not true. Take any $f \in C^1(\overline{\Omega}) \subset H^1(\Omega)$ with non-zero trace. Any multivariable polynomial is such an example. Take $g=c \neq 0$ to be constant. Certainly $g \in W^{1,\infty}(\Omega)$. But the trace operator is also linear and hence
$$
\gamma(f)=\gamma(gf)=\gamma(cf)=c\gamma(f),
$$
which is a contradiction unless $\gamma(f)=0$ a.e.
The statement should be true if you require $f \in H^1_0(\Omega)$.
Edit: In that case, $g$ is Lipschitz continuous and hence can be extended to a function which is continuous up to the boundary. Approximate $f$ by a sequence in $f_n \in C_c^{\infty}(\Omega)$. In that case, $f_n g \in H^1_0 (\Omega) \cap C(\overline\Omega) $ and therefore $\gamma(f_n g)=0$ for all $n$. However, $f_ng \to fg$ and by continuity of the traceoperator, we have $\gamma(f)=0=\gamma(fg)$.

And if I assume that last thing, how would be the proof? Because probably is a mistake in the exercise. Thank you so much, I'll tell my professor

Nevermind, if $f |in H_0^1(\Omega)$ then the trace is $0$ in both sides

Added a proof. Take a look if it seems alright to you. And yes, the trace would then be zero both times. But as I have shown earlier, this is a requirement.
